# Seeing No CUDA capable GPU detected after i upgraded to cuda 6.5 from 5.5

Tags: cuda

Hey i am receving the error : No CUDA capable GPU detected 
after i upgraded from Cuda 5.5 to Cuda 6.5 .

Nvidia driver version i have is 331.49 .

Is this compatible for running 6.5 version or what is the best stable version for cuda 6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA 6.5 requires a r340 driver or newer.  On linux that would be 340.29 or higher.

331.49 won't work.  Whatever method you used to "upgrade" from 5.5 to 6.5 was incomplete.

There are [getting started guides](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#getting-started-guides) for each supported OS that may help.

If you just want to load a new driver, you can select a driver appropriate for your GPU and OS at http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score -1):

The best stable version driver for 6.5 is 346. 
you can uninstall completely the driver by

```
sudo nvidia-uninstall
```

and then add xorg-edgers repository, and next update the apt-get and install the desired driver version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and then run

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and reboot after that.

After startup verify the driver installation by:

```
nvidia-smi
```

It should print out desirable output. which is some information about the GPU.
And after you can verify the cuda installation by running `deviceQuery` in samples.